# Сортировка в таблице по полям vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

Пропсами прилетает массив с данными и массив с названием колонок, нужно сделать функционал чтобы при нажатии на название колонки таблица сортировалась в зависимости от нажатой колонки. Проблема в том, что нам постоянно прилетают разные названия колонок и разные данные, поэтому нужно сделать функцию адаптивной под разные колонки

```
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th
          class="admin-table__input-wrapper"
          v-for="(col, index) in columns"
          :key="index"
        >
          <span 
            @click="[
              col.sortBy && sortBy()
            ]" 
            :class="col.sortBy && 'sortBy'"
          >
            {{ col.label }}
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr
        ref="tableRow"
        class="table__row"
        v-for="(el, index) in data"
        :key="index"
      >
        <td class="body-3" v-for="(col, index) in columns" :key="index">
          {{ el[col.field] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "AdminTable",
  layout: "admin",
  props: {
    columns: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    data: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy() {
      this.columns.forEach((col) => {
        this.data.sort((a, b) => {
          return a[col.field].localeCompare(b[col.field]); // Попытка сделать адаптивность под любые поля
        });
      });
      // this.data.sort((a, b) => { Рабочий вариант, но сортировка работает только по полю fullname
      //   return a.fullname.localeCompare(b.fullname);
      // });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Компонента с которой прилетают данные:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body p-0">
      <AdminTable :columns="columns" :data="trainers"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AdminTable from "@/components/sections/admin-table";

export default {
  layout: "admin",
  components: {
    AdminTable,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      trainers: [
        {
          id: 1312,
          fullname: "Paris Stanley",
          email: "Curved@gmail.com",
        },
        {
          id: 1421,
          fullname: "Layne Hensley",
          email: "Pumped@gmail.com",
        },
      ],
      columns: [
        {
          field: "id",
          label: "Id",
          search: true,
          sortBy: true,
        },
        {
          field: "fullname",
          label: "Full Name",
          search: true,
          sortBy: true,
        },
        {
          field: "email",
          label: "Email",
          search: true,
          sortBy: true,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Передайте в метод индекс колонки и сортируйте

Answer (score 1):

1. Не правильно сортировать данные внутри компонента таблицы. Вы изменяете `props`, что само по себе запрещено во `Vue`.  Соответственно логика сортировки должна быть на уровень выше, а компонент таблицы максимум что может делать - сообщать о нужде в сортировке. Таким образом это будет самостоятельный компонент который можно будет легко переиспользовать с разной логикой сортировки. Почитайте о принципе инверсии зависимостей.
2. Как следствие с первого пункта, компонент таблицы будет сообщать по какому полю нужно сортировать. `$emit('update:sort', col.field)`
3. Компонент вышестоящий будет принимать `@update:sort="sortBy"` и в методе будет итерация по нужному полю